# How to solve Js load error? Shipping Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, extensions, shipping-methods, server-setup

I am using [Sendle shipping extension](http://joovii.com/shipping-method/sendle.html/), this extension work as, if you give zip code gives auto suggestion of city, after I migrate server, the auto suggestion not working.

The extension developer said, JS not loading in your server and give the exact js file.

How can I test with server and how can I solve this issue?

Note : Sendle EXtension Demo Site : 
View Source file : view-source:http://sendlemag1demo.nerdster.com.au/index.php/checkout/onepage (Copy the link and paste your browser)
line 41 load the Js, compare to my checkout page the js file missing, but if i run the js file manually its showing. may i know whats is the possible reason not loading my Js.